# how to extract all details from a table using year in where clause

Tags: mysql

I am new in Mysql.
I just want to extract all data in my employee data using year in where class.
I have only date column in my table and i want to execute a query using year to extract all data from from my table employee.

example:
2012-02-01 is date value in my column name date.

select * from emp where ??.

Comment: [apparently, the date/time functions are hard to find?](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) (use `YEAR(column)='whatever year you want'`

Answer (score 2):

Easy and straight forward,

```
Select * FROM EMPLOYEETABLE WHERE YEAR(DateOfEmployeeColumn) = YourSuppliedYear
```

Answer (score 0):

select * from emp where YEAR(date_column)

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE YEAR(date) = 2008` Should work!